# Pandas Merging multiple DataFrames generating huge data

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, join, merge

### Table 1

### EncounterID | uniqueID | Some other cols

### Table 2

### EncounterID  |  Some other cols

I have Table3, Table 4, Table 5 with EncounterID and other columns.

UniqueIDs are only present in Table 1. All EncouterIDs can be fetched from table 1 based on UniqueID and there can be multiple EncounterIDs for a single UniqueID

Below is my implementation:

```
uniquePatientIds=Table1.UNIQUE_ID.unique()
for id in uniquePatientIds:
    Record = Table1.loc[Table1['UNIQUE_ID'] == id]
    ptonTable2 = pd.merge(Record, Table2, on = 'ENCOUNTER_ID' , how='left')
    ptonTable3 = pd.merge(ptonTable2, Table3, on = 'ENCOUNTER_ID' , how='left')
    ptonTable4 = pd.merge(ptonTable3, Table4, on = 'ENCOUNTER_ID' , how='left')
    ptonTable5 = pd.merge(ptonTable4, Table5, on = 'ENCOUNTER_ID' , how='left')
    print(ptonTable5.shape)
```

Table1 has 6 ENCOUNTER_ID for 1 UNIQUE_ID (6, 24)
Similiarly,
Table2 has(3, 7)
Table3 has (55, 10)
Table4 has (24, 22)
Table5 has (59, 17)

When performing the "Left outer join" final output has (19854, 76), this UNIQUE_ID has very few ENCOUNTER_ID when compared to other UNIQUE_ID, so few other outputs have '100 thousands' of rows.

I have checked for duplicates too, there aren't any duplicates being generated.

I am new to pandas and DataFrames. Can someone help how to fetch all encounterID rows and columns from all the tables

Comment: Do any ENCOUNTER_ID's show up multiple times in any of your dataframes?

Comment: Yes, there are few ENCOUNTER_ID's that show up multiple times

Comment: That's at least part of the reason for te large # of rows. This example with 3 dfs in a list. They have 1 encounter id, but it shows up 5,10, and 15 times in the dfs. The resulting df has 5*10*15 = 750 rows.


`df_list = [pd.DataFrame({'encounter_id':['id1' for i in range(5*(j+1))],'y':np.random.randint(low=1,high=10,size=5*(j+1))}) for j in range(3)] #all have 1 unique id`

`merged_df = df_list[0].copy()`

`for i in range(1,len(df_list)):
    merged_df = pd.merge(merged_df,df_list[i],how='left',on='encounter_id')`

`print(merged_df.shape) #(750,4)`